# How to use resolution in this formula with XOR?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, satisfiability

Transform the set of causes of the given formula are below:

$\overline{x}\lor y.....(1)$

$\overline{y}\lor x.....(2)$

$\overline{z}\lor w.....(3)$

$\overline{w}\lor z.....(4)$

$\overline{s}\lor \overline{t}.....(5)$

$s\lor t.....(6)$

$\overline{x}\lor \overline{z}\lor\overline{s}.....(7)$

$\overline{x}\lor z\lor s.....(8)$

$\overline{z}\lor x\lor s.....(9)$

$\overline{s}\lor x\lor z.....(10)$

$\overline{y}\lor \overline{w}\lor\overline{t}.....(11)$

$\overline{y}\lor w\lor t.....(12)$

$\overline{w}\lor y\lor t.....(13)$

$\overline{t}\lor y\lor w.....(14)$

I need to refute using resolution.

***My try:***

Resolution of (1) and (9) implies,
$\overline{z}\lor y\lor s.....(15)$

Resolution of (2) and (8) implies,
$\overline{y}\lor z\lor s.....(16)$

Resolution of (3) and (10) implies,
$\overline{s}\lor w\lor x.....(17)$

Resolution of (4) and (7) implies,
$\overline{w}\lor \overline{x}\lor\overline{s}.....(18)$

Resolution of (5) and (12) implies,
$\overline{s}\lor \overline{y}\lor w.....(19)$

Resolution of (6) and (11) implies,
$\overline{y}\lor s\lor \overline{w}.....(20)$

Resolution of (15) and (16) implies,
$\overline{z}\lor z\lor s.....(21)$

Resolution of (17) and (18) implies,
$\overline{s}\lor \overline {x}\lor x.....(22)$

Resolution of (19) and (14) implies,
$\overline{s}\lor \overline {t}\lor w.....(23)$

Resolution of (13) and (20) implies,
$s \lor \overline {w} \lor t.....(24)$

My question is  how to proceed from here? How to get empty set, $\Phi$, which is unsatisfiable? Is there any easy approach exists to reach $\Phi$?

Comment: @Amitai, no, you can't. You do either z and z' or y and y'. Not both at the same time. It's against resolution rule.

Comment: @Amitai if you have (y ' or x' ) and (x or y) then you get either (x or x' ) or (y or y') . Not phi.

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry about the wrong answer. I tried to apply other techniques for this and realised I can't.

Comment: @Amitai, is there any solution for this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with the XOR in the title ... but I do know that this clause set is satisfiable (see my Answer below), and thus you won;t be able to derive the empty clause (contradiction) from this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With these, the best thing to do is to try and decrease the number of variables that you are working with. Fortunately, you can do that here quite nicely. You can use statements 1 through 6 to gradually replace all $x$'s with $y$'s, all $z$'s with $w$'s, and all $s$'s with $t$'s in statements 7 through 10, so that together with statements 11 through 14 you end up with $8$ statements that involve $y$, $w$, and $t$ only. And from there, it's only a few more steps to the contradiction.

Replace all $x$'s with $y$'s:

(15) $\overline{y}\lor \overline{z}\lor\overline{s}.....(2,7)$

(16) $\overline{y}\lor z\lor s.....(2,8)$

(17) $\overline{z}\lor y\lor s.....(1,9)$

(18) $\overline{s}\lor y\lor z.....(1,10)$

Replace all $z$'s with $w$'s

(19) $\overline{y}\lor \overline{w}\lor\overline{s}.....(4,15)$

(20) $\overline{y}\lor w\lor s.....(3,16)$

(21) $\overline{w}\lor y\lor s.....(4,17)$

(22) $\overline{s}\lor y\lor w.....(3,18)$

Replace all $s$'s with $t$'s

(23) $\overline{y}\lor \overline{w}\lor t.....(6,19)$

(24) $\overline{y}\lor w\lor \overline{t}.....(5,20)$

(25) $\overline{w}\lor y\lor \overline{t}.....(5,21)$

(26) $t \lor y\lor w.....(6,22)$

OK, and so now combine these with 11 through 14:

(27) $\overline{y}\lor \overline{w}.....(11,23)$

(28) $\overline{y}\lor w.....(12,24)$

(29) $\overline{w}\lor y.....(13,25)$

(30) $y\lor w.....(14,26)$

Almost there:

(31) $\overline{y}.....(27,28)$

(32) $y .... (29,30)$

(33) $\bot .... (31,32)$

Comment: See, my updated question, I just forgotten to use complement of s and t. Sorry for error.

Comment: @Brett  Looks like you changed 5 and 6?

Comment: Yes, for that 23 and 24 also changed.

Comment: @Brett  OK, updated my Answer

Comment: It is Great answer..